# Rebuilding of Garland theme on database migration

Tags: 7, migrations

I work on localhost and in the evening I migrate the database, default/files folder, sites/all folder to the production site and restore the site database backup using drush sqlq command.

But on restore the Garland(sub-themed one) on one D6 site breaks. So I'd need to login and go to this theme and them manually do "Save Configuration" in this theme. I also run cron and cache clean all using drush **before and after** this drush sqlq restore.

In the same way I've another D7 site with Bartik theme which misses only header colors - which I restore by following the same procedure.

I'm also following the same workflow for other four D7 sites which work fine and show no such issues.

I've automatized this procedure except for the inconvenience for this manual intervention for my 2 out of 6 sites.

Is there any way to regenerate the theme css or the other files by using say Drush?

Comment: Do you have access to the error_log? That way you could see where your theme breaks.

Comment: Next time when I migrate, I'll check the log

Comment: No, I mean when you try to use the broken theme that you have moved to your server, does it report something on the error_log file located on your server. Do you have access to that file?

Comment: you're right. In one my D6 Gardland custom theme, I can see the logo url as icc/sites/default/files.... where the url is http ://localhost/icc for my site. The same path is coming in the live site. Upload a new logo gives the same problem.